# Explain partitions

Tags: partitioning, explain

What does the possible keys, reference and rows indicate in explain partitions?

I have used partitions on the table and I executing the explain partitions  with a query:

```
select count(inspection_result) 
  from gtron_component_info 
  where (inspection_time between "2015-06-01" and "2015-06-30")
  and inspection_result= 1 
  and part_type = "39000048"
  and location = "1"
```

It gives partition the `P11` and `P12`.

But the same query for one week time

```
select count(inspection_result) from gtron_component_info 
  where (inspection_time between "2015-06-29" and "2015-07-02") 
  and inspection_result= 1 
  and part_type = "39000048" 
  and location = "1"
```

It gives `P1`, `P11` and `P12`.

- P1 consists of values less than `"15-01-15"`
- P11 consists of values less than `"15-06-15"`
- p12 consists of values less than `"15-07-01"`

Can anyone explain me the reason and the columns in 'explain partitions'
 output?

Comment: Does the table use TO_DAYS() as partitioning function? https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49754

Comment: what database system are you using? Please add appropriate tagw.

Comment: yes.. its using To_days amd system is MYSQL